# Cannot browse to most websites, on my PC only

Tags: networking, internet, dns, windows-domain, browsing

I cannot load most websites on my PC. Using Chrome, FireFox, or IE I get the "this webpage is not available" error. I've tried and failed to ping the websites that won't load. I'm in a domain environment, and other computers in the domain are functioning properly. I updated and scanned with Malwarebytes. Nothing was found. I've also been keeping an eye on the Network tab of Resource Monitor, but nothing jumps out to me as malicious.

I have "cloud" software installed that is working properly (dropbox, evernote, logmein). My LAN connectivity is working properly.

The websites do not even attempt to load. Typically you get a second or two where the browser attempts to load the site, but if it doesn't work its immediate. This makes me think it would be a DNS issue, but I've got my domain controllers as my DNS. The DCs can load the websites, and all the other PCs on my domain can load them as well.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: So, did you try to perform some DNS lookups to test your theory?

Comment: This could be a number of things. Check both your browser's, your system's and your router's/modem's DNS settings. Are they all the same? Try using Google's `8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4` If you have a proxy try disabling it, if you have a firewall try disabling it, also take a look at your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).

Comment: Check to see if you have a system proxy set in Internet Options that may be broken.

Comment: Since you are in a domain environment, which sounds like a corporate network, have you talked to the IT folks who control it?

Comment: Hosts file is empty. No proxy. No firewall on my machine. I changed my local DNS to google and the sites still don't resolve. I am IT staff, but I've never come across this. I like to ask you guys when I'm trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 4):

There's a file called *hosts* that can override DNS lookup. You'll need administrative privileges to edit it.

To view that file on XP you can simply start Notepad from any administrator account. On Vista, 7 or 8 you can type 'notepad' in the start menu search box, then right-click its icon and choose *Run as administrator*.

In Notepad, click *File -> Open* and type the following as a filename:

```
%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

If there are any sites that don't work in there, delete these lines and save the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my hosts file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

A complete scan with MalwareBytes found additional malware. After removing and restarting everything is functioning.